# В чем проблема перехода по кнопке с одной формы в другую и обратно? С++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Код первой формы

```
#pragma once
#include "MyForm1.h"

namespace LogicColor {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
protected: 

protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MyForm::typeid));
        this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this->pictureBox1->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"pictureBox1.BackgroundImage")));
        this->pictureBox1->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Center;
        this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 81);
        this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
        this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(537, 133);
        this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
        this->pictureBox1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::pictureBox1_Click);
        // 
        // MyForm
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Center;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(602, 282);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
        this->Name = L"MyForm";
        this->Text = L"MyForm";
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void pictureBox1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             this->Hide();
             MyForm1 ^ F;
             F=gcnew MyForm1();
             F->Show();
         }
};
}
```

Код второй формы:

```
#pragma once 
#include "MyForm.h"

namespace LogicColor {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for MyForm1
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
protected: 

protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MyForm1::typeid));
        this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this->pictureBox1->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"pictureBox1.BackgroundImage")));
        this->pictureBox1->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Center;
        this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(167, 90);
        this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
        this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(257, 63);
        this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
        this->pictureBox1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm1::pictureBox1_Click);
        // 
        // MyForm1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(592, 246);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
        this->Name = L"MyForm1";
        this->Text = L"MyForm1";
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void pictureBox1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             this->Hide();
             MyForm ^ F;
             F=gcnew MyForm();
             F->Show();
         }
};
}
```

В итоге:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На кнопки вписываю:

```
private: System::Void pictureBox1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             this->Hide();
             MyForm ^ F;
             F=gcnew MyForm();
             F->Show();
         }
```

Comment: Проблема перекрестных ссылок. Каждый год помногу раз всплывает на всех форумах. Короткого ответа не имеет. Адекватное решение одно: переход на C#.

Comment: Смотрите понятный и лаконичный [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677984/184217), как разруливаются ссылки классов (форм) друг на друга. Проблема в дизайнере WinForm, который вставляет обработчики событий в файл `.h`. Он не рассчитан на написание мало-мальски серёзных приложений. Нужно вручную переносить код в `.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Код на кнопку

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    MyForm1 ^fm;
    fm = gcnew MyForm1();
    fm->Show();
}
```

И не забудь подключить 2-ую форму

```
#pragma 
#include "MyForm1.h"

namespace FormToForm {
```

Comment: а тепер как назад перейти на первую ? ?