# Существуют ли правила подключения include-файлов в С++?

Tags: c++

Написал проект, в котором используется много файлов, в каждом по несколько классов и они ссылаются друг на друга. И вот в какой-то момент возникла неразрешимая ошибка с которой не так просто сразу разобраться. Используется класс, который как бы не описан (хотя, конечно же, он описан)...

Может существует какие-то правила, используя которые не возникнет таких ошибок?

Comment: Текст ошибки в студию! Но скорее всего ваша проблема решается банально предварительным объявлением класса.

Comment: Error C3927 '->': trailing return type is not allowed after a non-function declarator

Comment: Ну а теперь не помешало бы увидеть [mcve]. И добавляйте полезную информацию в вопрос путём его редактирования, а не просто в комментариях.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Сам при изучении наступал на грабли, информации полезной в интернете почти не было

Comment: Есть только полный пример, если есть время: https://github.com/sitev/cms

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку вы не предоставили пример кода, предположу, что ваша проблема в следующем. У вас есть два класса, которые ссылаются друг на друга. В этом случае, в каком бы порядке не подключать заголовочные файлы, один из них подключится первым, и не увидит второй.

Для таких случаев стоит использовать предварительное объявление классов.
Пример:

```
// bear.h
#ifndef BEAR_H
#define BEAR_H

class balalaika; // не #include "balalaika.h"

class bear
{
    balalaika* p_b;
public:
    void play();
};

#endif
```

```
// bear.cpp
#include "bear.h"
#include "balalaika.h"

void bear::play()
{
    // тут можно использовать балалайку
    p_b->strings->...
}
```

```
// balalaika.h
#ifndef BALALAIKA_H
#define BALALAIKA_H

class bear; // не #include "bear.h"

class balalaika
{
    bear* p_owner;
public:
    int strings;
    // ...
};

#endif
```

```
// balalaika.cpp
#include "balalaika.h"
#include "bear.h"

// ...
```

Comment: Два самовара чая этому барину!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Исполать вам!